# How to Show Image View in android?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am sorry I am very beginner in java/android, maybe this question is too bad.

I want to display my icon in splash screen, but if I use ic_launcher it's size is too small. (192x192)

When I generate ic_launcher from new image asset it generates an image with size 512x512 in `"app\src\main\ic_launcher-web.png"`

Can I display that image?
I think I can change `@mipmap/ic_launcher` to some path/image location. So, I don't need to copy my image to drawable/mipmap directory.

> ```
>         <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
>         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
>         android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
> ```

I have been looking for it and did not find it.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your original image in `res/drawable/youimage.png`. Then call it from

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/yourimage.png" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is it means I have to copy my image to drawable/mipmap directory?

Comment: Copy in the res/drawable folder will do. Unless you have various resolution of your drawings (e.g. hdpi, mdpi etc.)